# Authorization (subgraph access control) in Neo4j with python driver

Tags: python, neo4j, authorization, graph-databases, py2neo

I have some employee data in which there are 3 different roles. Let's say **CEO**, **Manager** and **Developer**.

CEO can access the whole graph, managers can only access data of some people (their team) and developers can not access employee data.

How should I assign subgraph access to user roles and implement this using **Python**?
There are good solutions and comprehensive libraries and documentations but only in Java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to write procedures for custom roles to implement subgraph access control using Python. It is only possible in Java.

A workaround might be to indirektly implement it using phyton by adding properties to nodes and relationship storing the security levels for these nodes and relationships. Checking the secutiry level of a user it might be possible to use a phyton visualization that checks the properties to only display nodes and relationships that are in agreement with the user security level.

Answer (score 1):

The enterprise edition of neo4j has built-in [procedures for managing users and roles](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/procedures/) that you access using Cypher queries. So, you just need to know how to perform Cypher queries in Python. You should also be aware that in a neo4j cluster, [user and role assignments are not propagated automatically](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/propagate-users-and-roles/).

There are a set of built in [native roles with specific access privileges](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/native-user-role-management/native-roles/), but you can also create your own custom roles. You will probably want to create custom roles for your scenario.

[Managing subgraph access control](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/security/authentication-authorization/subgraph-access-control/) requires modifying the neo4j configuration file. That is not something you can do programmatically.

Comment: I know about user and role management and yes, I probably want to create custom roles. The new custom roles have no rights but in the neo4j configuration fie I can assign procedures to them that they are allowed to call. I think that was what you were saying.
Now, my question is how I write the procedures for the subgraph access control and if that is only possible in java or if it is also possible in python.
Thank you for your help.